# date_parse_from_format to unix timestamp

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the `date_parse_from_format()` method:

```
$parsed = date_parse_from_format("Y d M H:i T", '2012 28 Nov 21:00 CET');
```

> Returns associative array with detailed info about given date.

This will return an array with some date info. But is there any way to convert it to a unix timestamp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Johan,

Heres an exact example of how to implement mktime into your scenario:

```
$parsed = date_parse_from_format("Y d M H:i T", '2012 28 Nov 21:00 CET');
$new = mktime(
        $parsed['hour'], 
        $parsed['minute'], 
        $parsed['second'], 
        $parsed['month'], 
        $parsed['day'], 
        $parsed['year']
);
echo $new; //returns: 1354136400
```

---

For future reference, you can use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on an array to see how to access the nested values.

**var_dump of $parsed**

```
array (size=16)
  'year' => int 2012
  'month' => int 11
  'day' => int 28
  'hour' => int 21
  'minute' => int 0
  'second' => int 0
  'fraction' => boolean false
  'warning_count' => int 0
  'warnings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'error_count' => int 0
  'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'is_localtime' => boolean true
  'zone_type' => int 2
  'zone' => int -60
  'is_dst' => boolean false
  'tz_abbr' => string 'CET' (length=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an example

Answer (score 4):

You can get the UNIX time-stamp by trying to use [mktime()](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) for a date.

**For Example:**

```
echo mktime(12, 20, 0, 10, 4, 2012 );
```

You will get the output like that `1349353200`

And if you want AM/PM just add 12 to hours if PM.

**For Example:**

```
mktime($isAM ? $hrs : ($hrs + 12), $mins, $secs, $m, $d, $y);
```

and you can also use strtotime():

[strtotime()](http://ie.php.net/strtotime) - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
echo strtotime("2012-11-03 11:24:00PM");
```

You will get the output like that `1351985040`

Answer (score 4):

In PHP >=5.3, you can use the DateTime constructor which functions exactly like `date_parse_from_format`. Bonus points: it's a one-liner.

For instance, to convert a date in a UK format to a UNIX timestamp, we can do:

```php
DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y, H:i", '27/03/2020, 22:00')->getTimestamp()

-> int(1585346400)
```

Answer (score 0):

mktime() should suit your needs perfectly :) Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php to see how you can use it!