# Turn german string into Timestamp

Tags: php

I'm a bit afraid to ask this question, since I'm sure it has already been answered here, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find any solution...

My Problem is pretty simple. I got a string like

> Freitag, 17. Februar 2017 08:00

and need to convert it to a timestamp or similar, where I can do operations on the time (e.g. subtract 30 hours).
As you might notice the string is German, so from my tries with `strtotime()`, didn't work. I'm absolutely out of ideas to solve this. Unfortunately it's not an option to fetch the string in English... :/

I'm happy for any help! Thanks!

Comment: See like [this example at eval.in](https://eval.in/733339). You just need to translate the month to english and can use `date_parse_from_format`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Unfortunately I can't mark your comment as the solution :(

Comment: Glad it helped, I put as an answer (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to translate the month and use [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).

```
$month = [
'Januar' => 'january', 'Februar' => 'february', 'März' => 'march',
'Mai' => 'may', 'Juni' => 'june', 'Juli' => 'july', 'Oktober' => 'october',
'November' => 'november', 'Dezember' => 'december'];

$mres = date_parse_from_format('j. F Y H:i', strtr($str, $month));
```

(if utf-8 use `utf8_encode` for non-ascii words). Then use [`mktime` to generate timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625922/date-parse-from-format-to-unix-timestamp).

```
$timestamp = mktime($mres['hour'],  $mres['minute'], $mres['second'], 
                    $mres['month'], $mres['day'],    $mres['year']);
```

[PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/737048)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)? Seems to have pretty good language support. *Viel gluck*. Steve